# How do I make the "1.9.2" Ruby string point to the final release with RVM?

Tags: bash, ruby, rvm

I'm using [RVM](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com) to manage my Ruby environment on OSX, and currently it's interpreting '1.9.2' as `ruby-1.9.2-rc2` instead of the final release. How can I update this to make it behave as expected?

Comment: @Adam this doesn't seem to me that it has anything to do with unix... this seems like a Ruby question... SO? I've no clue what this has to do with bash

Comment: @xenoterracide RVM is a Ruby version manager written in bash, and entirely specific to unix systems. It manipulates your shell environment to allow you to use multiple versions & gemsets in one environment.

Comment: @xenoterracide I was going to add `rvm` and `ruby` as tags but I'm not allowed.

Comment: @Adam so it's perlbrew for ruby...

Comment: @xenoterracide Yes, same idea but with the added capability of being able to define multiple independent gemsets in addition to Ruby installations.

Comment: @Adam so it's App::perlbrew + local::lib ... at least if I'm guessing correctly at Ruby terminology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this got no response I asked this question and got [an answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3620798/) from [michaelmichael](https://stackoverflow.com/users/150746/michaelmichael).

> Make sure you've updated rvm with the `rvm update` command. From there you can install 1.9.2 with `rvm install 1.9.2`. It'll install and compile ruby 1.9.2-p0. From there, it should interpret `1.9.2` as the final release. I'm also on a mac, and this worked for me after having rc2 installed.